# How to get accessToken from React context API and put it into Apollo's HttpLink?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I've the following project structure(roughly),

```
src/
  index.tsx -> entry point for React
  App.tsx 
  client.tsx -> Apollo client definition
  components/
    TokenProvider.tsx -> Provider for accessToken
```

`index.tsx` looks like following, it provides `apollo-client` and the `accessToken` to whole App.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";

import { TokenProvider } from "./components/TokenContext";
import client from "./client";
import App from "./App";

render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <TokenProvider>
      <App />
    </TokenProvider>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`client.tsx` looks like following,

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000",
  credentials: "include",
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: httpLink,
});

export default client;
```

I am trying to do some authorization stuff so I need to add `authorization` header to the `HttpLink` in `client.tsx`.

So in `index.tsx`, I need something like the following,

```js
// in index.tsx

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000",
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    authorization: `bearer ${accessToken}`, // I need this <---
  },
});
```

The problem is, `accessToken` variable can be accessed through `useContext` API, because it is provided by a `React Context`. But `client.tsx` is not a React component so I cannot access it.

I set accessToken either in `user login` or in the beginning of the App if there is refresh token available. So in `App.tsx`,

```js
// in App.tsx
  useEffect(() => {
    // prevent login in every refresh
    refreshAccessToken().then((accessToken) => {
      // dispatch comes from `TokenProvider`
      dispatch({ type: CHANGE_TOKEN, payload: { accessToken } });
    });
  }, [])
```

Is there any way to overcome this? Maybe I shouldn't provide accessToken with Context API, what are the other solutions?

Comment: Where else do you need to use the accessToken? Where does it come from?

Comment: @bmdev, I've edited post to try to address  your questions. It comes either login or at the beginning of the app if refresh token is available as cookie. I want to use information inside the access token thats why I am providing it to whole App.

Comment: thanks! gonna answer now